# sharedPreferences apply() saves all the above or just the last one? How it works?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences

My question is very simple, but I did not found an answer (sorry if it is somewhere and just did not found it).

How `sharedpreferences.editor.apply()` works?

To be clear, I have this code for example:

```
MainActivity.editor.putBoolean(somestring, someboolean);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
MainActivity.editor.putInt(somestring, someint);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
MainActivity.editor.putString(somestring,somestring);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
MainActivity.editor.putLong(somestring, somelong);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
MainActivity.editor.putLong(somestring, somelong);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
MainActivity.editor.putBoolean(somestring, someboolean);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
```

This works in my project. But is it better regarding performance to use this above or this below?

```
MainActivity.editor.putBoolean(somestring, someboolean);
MainActivity.editor.putInt(somestring, someint);
MainActivity.editor.putString(somestring,somestring);
MainActivity.editor.putLong(somestring, somelong);
MainActivity.editor.putLong(somestring, somelong);
MainActivity.editor.putBoolean(somestring, someboolean);
MainActivity.editor.apply();
```

Basically, the code above is correct?
 Will it work for all the `putSomething` above or `apply()` works just for one `putSomething`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last one for sure.  Both `apply()` and `commit()` will save all changes. Why would you even want to apply the changes multiple times? Although the last one is better for performance, you won't really notice because `apply()` is aSync. Yet, don't do unnecessary stuff. However `commit()` will decrease performance because it is not aSync.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You are really helpful and instructive!

Answer (score 1):

apply vs commit

The main different of using apply() and commit()

`.apply()` will save your changed in background thread.

`.commit()` will save your changed in main thread.

These two methods will produce same result.

Answer (score 0):

calling apply() once saves all the changes made with the editor object. So the code in below is the correct one. =)

Answer (score 0):

The code above is the best one, the method apply() will save all the SharedPreferences.Editor changes, and is unnecessary call it every time.

void apply ()

Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the SharedPreferences.

Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call apply wins.

If you want to know the best way to use SharedPreferences visit this site:

[Best Practices](http://blog.yakivmospan.com/best-practices-for-sharedpreferences/)

And a little bit documentation:

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)

Comment: that "Best Practices" page says *Sorry this site is not supported any more. This article has moved to http://blog.yakivmospan.com/best-practices-for-sharedpreferences/*  Useful info, can you please update the link?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your helpful links!